# Getting previous states in state_machine rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, state-machine

I am developing state machine using state_machine on rails, here i have different states which is defined , based on conditions state will change to another state . Here my question is how to get the previous state? and my second question is how to list all the states in state machine ?

> i will explain my question with example say i have 3 states say
>   state1,state2,state3 initially it will be in state1. when event1 is
>   executed state changes from state1=>state2 , now i wanted to know
>   which is my previous state. kindly help me out in figuring out this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for: https://github.com/wvanbergen/state_machine-audit_trail

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for the list of previous states from an object, i'm afraid u can not.
state_machine only changes a column value in your models database register, dosen't stores any type of history.

Please check solutions like acts_as_versioned (https://github.com/technoweenie/acts_as_versioned) to store and play with your models versions.

Also you want to check aasm gem https://github.com/rubyist/aasm

Cheers

Comment: hey thanks for reply , changing gem is not good idea i feel, but is there any logic which will serve the purpose

Answer (score 1):

I used paper_trail gem
and reified previous versions.

This allows me to follow up the sequence of states that the object went through.

With paper_trail you can even retrieve the Originator or Terminator of that state change.